Operators on the group of power series under composition
Let $G$ be the group with underlying set $tk[[t]]$ ($k$ is a field, let's start with $\text{char }k=0$) and composition as operation: $(fg)(t)=f(g(t))$. Have there been any studies as to what kinds of operators $G$ admits? As in, set-theoretic mappings $\mu$: $G\to G$, $g \mapsto {}^\mu g$, such that $^\mu(fg) = {}^\mu f {}^\mu g$? Maybe there is a complete description of the monoid, or at least a generating set is known?
Clearly conjugation by $h \in G$ is an example. Note that truncation to degree $n\ge 2$ is not an operator, though it satisfies ${}^\mu(fg)={}^\mu({}^\mu f {}^\mu g)$ (and is idempotent).

One can show that $G$ is an inverse limit of groups $G_n$ that look like polynomials with composition, taken modulo $t^{n+1}$ (this is just the image of your $n$th truncation operator $\tau_n$). So an automorphism of $G$ is the same data is a coherent sequence of automorphisms of these $G_n$s. That is, a family of automorphisms $\varphi_n : G_n \to G_n$ so that $\varphi_{n-1} \tau_{n-1} = \tau_{n-1} \varphi_n$. These might be easier to study, since they're dealing only with polynomials rather than power series
